# Gatling - could not be parsed into a proper Uri, missing scheme

Tags: scala, gatling

I have basic Gatling script in which I try to login to the app and that's it.
For some reason I get the error:

```
j.l.IllegalArgumentException: "https://my-site.com/"login could not be parsed into a proper Uri, missing scheme
```

It looks to me like it has appended at the end of the baseUrl quotation mark.

This is my simulation class:

```
package simulations.stage

import io.ecx.steps.{Config, Login}
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

import scala.concurrent.duration._

class RampUsersLoadSimulations extends Simulation{

  val httpConf = http.baseUrl(Config.baseUrl)
    .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36")
    .inferHtmlResources()
    .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate, br")

  before {
    println(s"Running for: ${Config.baseUrl}")
  }

  val login = scenario("Scenario: Login to the storefront")
    .exec(Login.login(Config.accounts))

  setUp(
    login.inject(
      nothingFor(5 seconds),
      atOnceUsers(Config.userCount),
      rampUsers(Config.userCount) during(Config.rampDuration seconds)
    ).protocols(httpConf)
  ).maxDuration(Config.testDuration seconds)
}
```

This is my login step implementation:

```
package io.ecx.steps

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

object Login {

  def login(accountsPath: String) = {
    val accounts = csv(accountsPath).random

    feed(accounts)
      .exec(http("Open login page")
      .get("login")
      .check(status.is(200)))
      .pause(2)
      .exec(http("Log in with credentials to the storefront")
        .post("j_spring_security_check")
        .formParam("email", "${username}")
        .formParam("password", "${password}"))
      .pause(5)
  }
}
```

This is my Config step implementation:

```
package io.ecx.steps

import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object Config {

  private def getProperty(propertyName: String, defaultValue: String) = {
    Option(System.getenv(propertyName))
      .orElse(Option(System.getProperty(propertyName)))
      .getOrElse(defaultValue)
  }

  def userCount: Int = getProperty("USERS", "5").toInt
  def rampDuration: Int = getProperty("RAMP_DURATION", "10").toInt
  def testDuration: Int = getProperty("DURATION", "12").toInt
  def environment:String = getProperty("ENVIRONMENT", "STAGE")

  val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
  val accounts = conf.getString("accounts")
  val baseUrl = if (environment == "STAGE") conf.getString("baseUrlStage") else conf.getString("baseUrlProd")
}
```

And in my properties file I have:

```
#COMMON
accounts=data/stage/accounts.csv

#STAGE
baseUrlStage="https://my-site.com/"

#PROD
baseUrlProd="TBD"
```

Can anybody help please :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is explicit: `"https://my-site.com/"login` could not be parsed into a proper Uri, missing scheme.

Indeed, the value in your property file is broken.

Instead of `baseUrlStage="https://my-site.com/"`, you should have `baseUrlStage=https://my-site.com/`.